# Width Animation Without changing Alignment in Android, Java

Tags: java, android

I have an imageview inside a Constraint Layout (root), the ImageView is aligned to the center. I want to increase the width of imageview using a simple animation, but this results in losing my center alignment, it just expands to the right instead of expanding to both sides equally. I tried scaleAniamtion, even thought the pivots help to align, my ImageView has corner radius (GradientDrawable) which also animates with the changing shape (Value Animator). I currently use ValueAnimator for both but the width animator gives me the mentioned trouble

```
    ValueAnimator radAnim= ValueAnimator.ofFloat(30f, 8f);
    radAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    radAnim.setDuration(400);
    radAnim.setStartDelay(2300);
    radAnim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        float val=(Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        defDraw.setCornerRadius(val);
    });

    ValueAnimator widAnim= ValueAnimator.ofFloat(defW, 5*defW);
    widAnim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    widAnim.setDuration(400);
    widAnim.setStartDelay(2300);
    widAnim.addUpdateListener(animation -> {
        float val=(Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams params = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) defaultV.getLayoutParams();
        params.width= (int)val;
        defaultV.setLayoutParams(params);
    });
```

Here `defaultV` is my Image View. I have been trying to find a similar problem in stackOverFlow and in internet generally, but no luck. I don't necessarily want to animate this using valueAnimator, ObjectAnimator or just Animation, i am fine with any path as long as it can,
Animate Width
Center Alignment
Not make it look weird via scaling (due to corner radius).

Thanks in advance for any help